# How to show list of unapplied changesets in Mercurial

Tags: mercurial, push

After pushing changesets to a repository called 'A' how can I see the list of changesets waiting to be applied when I am in 'A'?

Expanding on that,

1. In repo B I push changesets to repo B
2. I change to repo B
3. How can I list the changesets pushed in step 1?

Comment: You are after a list of changesets that have recently been pushed into a repo?

Comment: That would serve my current needs so yes.

Comment: What do you mean by "waiting to be applied"?

Comment: By "waiting to be applied" I mean the list of changesets that would be used if I did hg update.

Comment: In that case if you can work out the correct revset definition (the `-r` option) in my answer it should show you any changesets more recent than your current working directory.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "unapplied" changesets, however here's a couple thoughts.

You can easily see what changesets will be pushed to a repository by doing `hg outgoing` prior to doing the `hg push`. This will list all of the changesets that will be pushed using default options.

Similarly you can use `hg incoming` in the destination repository to show what changesets would be pulled from another repo.

As for "unapplied" changesets, if I assume you mean changesets that are newer than the working directory, you could use `hg log -r .:tip`, which should (I've not had a chance to test it) show all newer revisions, but not actually all recently-pushed ones.

Edit: I've updated the revision set in the `-r` option to something that should work. Have a look at revsets on the [Mercurial manpage](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html#revsets) for more possibilities.

Comment: The syntax is wrong:hg log -r "parents():"
hg: parse error: missing argument

Comment: Sorry, I was writing that partly from memory - I'm currently on a machine with no Hg so can't provide a correction :(

Comment: I've tried something else - when I get home later I will try it out on a real system rather than using semi-educated guesswork :)

Comment: This command listed the changesets in the way I wanted: hg log -r .:tip

Comment: Additionally you could add the `-b branchname` option if you're focusing on a specific branch. Not sure how well that would work with the `-r .:tip` - I'm away from my Hg again :)

Answer (score 5):

```
$ hg summary
parent: 0:9f47fcf4811f 
 .
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: 2 new changesets (update) <<<<<
```

The `update` bit tells you what (I think) you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had written a different answer, but I ended up with a better way of doing what is needed here (an even better and definitive –for me– solution is at the end of this post, in the [EDIT] section).

Use `hg log`.

Specifically, issue an `hg sum` command first. This will give me:

```
parent: 189:77e9fd7e4554
 <some commit message>
branch: default
commit: (clean)
update: 2 new changesets (update)
```

To see what those 2 new changesets are made of, I use

```
hg log -r tip -r 2 -v
```

Obviously, `2` is to be replaced with the number of changesets that `hg sum` reports.

This works because `tip` will refer to the most recent (or "unapplied") changeset. By limiting the output to the 2 latest changes (`-l 2`), the information is shown only for those changesets that I'm interested in. With `-v`, the list of files affected by the changeset is also shown.

To make things simpler, I have defined a user command in my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias hglog="hg log -r tip -l $1"
```

This allows me to type `hg sum` (to get the number of pending/unapplied changesets) and then to type `hglog x` where `x` is the number of changesets revealed by `hg sum`.

There is probably a more complete way of doing this, for instance using custom templates, but I guess it's pushing things too far in terms of sophistication.

[EDIT] (**Third iteration**)
I have reached the most satisfying answer to this question by expanding on the alias idea so that I no longer have to type `hg sum`. My .bashrc file now contains this:

```
show_pending_changesets() {
  nb=$(hg sum | grep "update:" | sed 's/update: \([0-9]*\) .*/\1/');
  if [ `expr $nb + 1 2> /dev/null` ] ; then
    hg log -r tip -v -l $nb
  else 
    echo "Nothing new to report"
  fi ;
}
...
alias hgwhatsnew=show_pending_changesets
```

Explanation: I'm using `sed` to extract the number of changesets from the last line (which is the one that starts with `update:`) of the output of `hg sum`. That number is then fed to `hg log`. All I have to do then is to type `hgw` and tab-complete it. HTH